# Render from libgdx into a Java Image, completely off-screen

Tags: java, image, swing, libgdx

I am new to `libgdx`, and am trying to render (thumbnail-sized) images of ~100 objects from a working game engine into Java `Image`s that I can display in a `Swing` application.

I can render them on-screen within a [LwjglCanvas](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglCanvas.html) fine, and from there I can grab their pixels using `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels()` (trying to pass in a `BufferedImage`'s `getGraphics()` into the `LwjglCanvas.paint(graphics)` method results in nothing being rendered into `graphics`), and put those into a `BufferedImage`. However, this requires an existing, displayed `LwjglCanvas`; I simply cannot figure out how to do background-thread thumbnailing without rendering on-screen.

Attaching current code snippet (requires displayed image within canvas; executed within a `Runnable` posted to this canvas via `canvas.postRunnable()`).

```
// canvas is an LwjglAWTCanvas
int w = canvas.getGraphics().getWidth();
int h = canvas.getGraphics().getHeight();
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
WritableRaster wr = bi.getRaster();
byte[] bytes = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, w, h, false);
int[] pixel = new int[4];
for (int y = h-1, b = 0; y >=0 h; y--) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        pixel[0] = bytes[b++];
        pixel[1] = bytes[b++];
        pixel[2] = bytes[b++];
        pixel[3] = bytes[b++];
        wr.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
    }
}
image = bi; // image is the rendered output image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a [FrameBuffer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) object.  These are supported in OpenGL ES 2.0 and later, and allow you to run OpenGL draw commands into off-screen buffers.

I thought `getFrameBufferPixels` would work with the FBO, if the FBO is 'current', but I'm told it doesn't.  (It seems the primitives work with OpenGL, so I'm not sure if something is missing in libGDX or OpenGL ES.  See [FBOs render to texture and glReadPixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949112/fbos-render-to-texture-and-glreadpixels)).

Comment: I have browsed around for examples of using FBO for this scenario. However, it seems I would have to rewrite all the rendering (essentially re-implement the LwjglCanvas and helper classes) to direct rendering of the game objects (images, animations, ...) to the FBO, something that, as a gdx noob, I am reluctant to start...

Comment: @tucuxi I think you can just wrap your existing code in `fb.begin()` and `fb.end()` calls.  The state (the render target) is kept inside OpenGL, so you shouldn't have to change anything ... unless you're using java.awt primitives to render your game objects?

Comment: It is impossible to get pixels back from FBO by getFrameBufferPixels. But is is possible to render texture attached to FBO to Pixmap and then read pixels from there. Also using FBO will be more efficient than direct pixel access in color buffer.